# Error : Sorry there is a problem, default page not found?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

we have SharePoint 2013, lask week i had to reinstall .net framework 3 in my SharePoint Server, after restart server one of my site collections shows error.

it said default.aspx not found. i open site by SharePoint Designer, the file is there and it is checked in.I restore backup but it was not helpful.

i'm new in sharepoint and so confused , please help me !

there is ULS Log :

> Name=Request (GET:http://intranet/Pages/default.aspx)
>   Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=UserName, ClaimsCount=29
>   Spent 0 ms to bind 2671 byte file stream
>   Spent 0 ms to send 2671 byte file stream
>   Site=/
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=32/8856740172284
>   Background file fill operation caught exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobConfigurationException: No provider of type  found. Check the server configuration or install the provider on the client.
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.ProviderSession.Connect()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobCommand.ExecuteInternal()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobCommand.Execute()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.SqlRemoteBlob.OpenReadableBlobStream()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.SqlRemoteBlob.set_Position(Int64 value)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundRemoteBlobFileFiller.get_RBSStream()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundRemoteBlobFileFiller.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.DoNextOperation()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.Fill()  ExceptionType:      Configuration ExceptionCode:      ProviderInterfaceNotFound Request Information not set. Session Information not set. Provider Session Information: Provider Session Info: ProviderSession:         ProviderSession. Id: <1>, Name: , Type: , StoreVersion: <1.0.0.0>, Location:   Core Configuration:   Extended Configuration:
>   Failed to get document content data. Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobConfigurationException: No provider of type  found. Check the server configuration or install the provider on the client.
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.ProviderSession.Connect()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobCommand.ExecuteInternal()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobCommand.Execute()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.SqlRemoteBlob.OpenReadableBlobStream()
>    at Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.SqlRemoteBlob.set_Position(Int64 value)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundRemoteBlobFileFiller.get_RBSStream()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundRemoteBlobFileFiller.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.DoNextOperation()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPBackgroundFileFiller.Fill()
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocParams(SqlSession session, Guid guidSiteId, Int32 cbContent, Nullable`1 parentId, Guid docId, Nullable`1 level, SPChunkedArray`1 rgbContent, Byte[] rgbRbsId, Int64 bsn, Byte partition, Int32 pageSize, Boolean bStartFilling)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)  ExceptionType:      Configuration ExceptionCode:      ProviderInterfaceNotFound Request Information not set. Session Information not set. Provider Session Information: Provider Session Info: ProviderSession:         ProviderSession. Id: <1>, Name: , Type: , StoreVersion: <1.0.0.0>, Location:   Core Configuration:   Extended Configuration:
>   Could not get DocumentContent row: 0x80131500.
>   Spent 0 ms to bind -1 byte file stream
>   Failure when fetching document. 0x80070002
>   Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002
>   SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-3478474691-2185617923-3781020798-1118, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://intranet/_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master ,bPageView=1 ,bPageMode=0 ,bGetBuildDependencySet=1 ,bstrCurrentFolderUrl= ,iRequestVersion=0 ,bMainFileRequest=0
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002), StackTrace:
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformation(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& level, String& masterpageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCachedBuildDependencySet(HttpContext context, String virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
>    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)
>    at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (GetFileAndMetaInfo). Execution Time=36/3604173156085
>   Leaving Monitored Scope (GetWebPartPageContent). Execution Time=36/5621887698018
>   Spent 0 ms to bind 1251 byte file stream
>   Spent 15 ms to send 1251 byte file stream
>   Application error when access /Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx, Error=فایل /_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master پیدا نشد.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetDirectDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: فایل /_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master پیدا نشد.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetDirectDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: فایل /_catalogs/masterpage/seattle.master پیدا نشد.
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetDirectDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection& directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
>    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
>    at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>    at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of

- SharePoint 2013 is working with `.Net Framework 3.5` that will include `.Net Framework 3` and `.Net Framework 2`
- `.Net Framework 3.5` must be installed from the same `Windows media` version by adding New Features from the `Server Manager`.

For more details check [Install .NET 3.5 Framework on Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/08/30/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-on-windows-2012/)

- `.Net Framework 3.5` is a prerequisite for SharePoint so after it has been installed properly try to run SharePoint configuration wizard at all SharePoint Server within the farm.

Comment: i used command for disable and enable .net framework. and used the same media that being used for windows installation .

Comment: are you installed ?Net framework 3 or 3.5 ?

Comment: i ran 2 different commands, one for 3 and one for 3.5

Comment: Okay, try to mount your , and make sure the .Net Framework 3.5 has been selected and installed if not install it as the above link mentioned , then run SharePoint Configuration Wizard.